# как можно заменить много if

Tags: java

Как я могу упростить этот метод, чем можно заменить множество if?

```
private int initialPrintIndex(int printNumber){
        if(printNumber == 1){
            return 0;
        }
        if(printNumber == 2){
            return 4;
        }
        if(printNumber == 3){
            return 8;
        }
        if(printNumber == 4){
            return 12;
        }
        if(printNumber == 5){
            return 16;
        }
        if(printNumber == 6){
            return 20;
        }
        if(printNumber == 7){
            return 24;
        }
        if(printNumber == 8){
            return 28;
        }
        if(printNumber == 9){
            return 32;
        }
        if(printNumber == 0){
            return 36;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int[] printValues = new int[] {36, 0, 4, ...};
return printValues[printNumber];
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы

Answer (score 0):

```
private int initialPrintIndex(int printNumber){ 
int x = -1;
switch(printNumber){
case 1:
x = 0;
break;
case 2:
x = 4;
break;
case 3:
x = 8;
break;
case 4:
x = 12;
break;
case 5:
x = 16;
break;
case 6:
x = 20;
break;
case 7:
x = 24;
break;
case 8:
x = 28;
break;
case 9:
x = 32;
break;
case 0:
x = 36;
break;
default:
throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
}
return x;
}
```

Замена if на switch ...

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: как-то неудобно читать

Comment: Да , предыдущий ответ - вне конкуренции ...

Answer (score 0):

```
private int initialPrintIndex( int x ) {
int[] printValues = new int[] { 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36 };
if( x < printValues.length || x >= printValues.length ) {
throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
}
return printValues [ x ] ;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Там же все кратное 4. В "одну строку" делается:

```
private int initialPrintIndex(int printNumber){
    if (printNumber >= 0 && printNumber  < 10){ 
        return (((printNumber+9)%10)*4);
    }else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("");
    }
}
```